# How to use REGEXP_REPLACE for TO_CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to replace `,TO_CHAR(.""` for a String which I am generating dynamically.

I tried using

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(x_select_format,'\TO_CHAR(."")','');
```

which is not working. How can I make this work. I had to introduce `TO_CHAR` to use `COALESCE` with dates.

```
x_select_format1:= REGEXP_REPLACE(x_select_format,'\TO_CHAR(."")','');
x_select_format2:= REGEXP_REPLACE(x_select_format1,',TO_CHAR()','');
```

String is like -

```
COALEACE(TO_CHAR(MARS."ABC_DATE"),TO_CHAR(JUPITER."BCD_DATE"),TO_CHAR(."")) AS "Forecasted",
```

Comment: REPLACE(x_select_format,',TO_CHAR(."")',''); worked

Comment: Don't answer in comments. If you have something that worked the post it as an answer (self-answers are allowed and encouraged) and then you can mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78157033/how-to-use-regexp-replace-for-to-char#comment137788161_78157033), the string is fixed so regular expressions are not necessary and `REPLACE` can be used:

```sql
REPLACE(x_select_format,',TO_CHAR(."")')
```

As an aside, if you did want to fix your regular expression (although it would be more efficient to use `REPLACE`) then you need to use a back-slash to escape the characters with special meaning:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(x_select_format,',TO_CHAR\(\.""\)')
```